# Divisors of $5^{n!}-3^{n!}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the number of integers $k$ in $\{1, \dots , n \}$ such that $k \mid 5^{n!}-3^{n!}$.

I've been trying to see just by testing the natural numbers n one at a time, in hopes to see a pattern to this, without much success. I am wondering what I should be attempting to figure this out.

Comment: If you have been testing the natural numbers, can you state the results for $n=1, 2, 3, 4, 5$? If so, is there a pattern there?

Answer (score 2):

Even a bit more explicite:
We have by Euler's theorem that $$ a^{\varphi(m)}-b^{\varphi(m)} \equiv 0 \pmod m$$ where $\varphi(m)$ is the Euler's totient function. A simple consequence from this is, that also 
$$ a^{\varphi(m)\cdot x}-b^{\varphi(m) \cdot x}  \equiv 0 \pmod m$$
for any $x \gt 1$ .
We have also  $\varphi(m) \lt m$ .
Now look at the exponents in your formula: because they are factorials, they contain for some chosen $m \le n$ *all* numbers $k \lt m$. So one of those $k$ must be the $\varphi()$ of *m*.

Now proceed in thinking yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint to get you started.

$k\ |\ 5^{n!} - 3^{n!} \Rightarrow 5^{n!} \equiv 3^{n!} \bmod n$.

In turn, $5^{n!} \equiv 3^{n!} \bmod n$ is true if and only if

$$5^{n!} \equiv 3^{n!} \bmod p^k$$ for all primes $p$ such that $p^k\ |\ n$ and $p^{k+1}\not|\ n$

To help with that, note [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), and that $\phi(p^k) = (p-1)p^{k-1}$.

Comment: Similar to Seirios's answer, but spelling out a little more, and adding one more step to possibly break things down into smaller pieces down the road.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Because $\phi(n) \leq n$, you may use [Euler's totient theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).